# Nil Associations with Rails Fixtures... how to fix?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, tdd, fixtures

I have a Rails 5.1 project using rspec/fixtures and I am having trouble getting fixtures to load objects associated with belongs_to/has_one/has_many: the object I requested the fixture for comes back with its _id columns filled with a seemingly-random number and ActiveRecord sees the association as `nil`. This occurs on large classes with many associations as well as small data classes with only a few fields.

If, in my test code, I assign those associations with normal Ruby code, objects behave as normal and my tests pass. However when loading the same data through fixtures, associated records are not available and tests that require data spanning across associations fail.

As an example, here are two affected classes:

```
#app/models/location.rb
class Location < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :orders
  has_many :end_user
  belongs_to :retailer
  belongs_to :depot
end

#app/models/retailer.rb
class Retailer < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :locations
end
```

And here are two corresponding fixtures files:

```
#spec/fixtures/locations.yml
loc_paris:
  retailer: ret_europe (Retailer)
  name: "Paris"
  nickname: "paris"

loc_washington:
  retailer: ret_usa (Retailer)
  name: "Washington"
  nickname: "washington"

#spec/fixtures/retailers.yml
ret_europe:
  name: "AcmeCo France"
  nickname: "acmecofr"
  currency_type: "EUR"

ret_usa:
  name: "AcmeCo USA"
  nickname: "acmecousa"
  currency_type: "USD"
```

With the above data, running `pp locations(:loc_paris)` results in:

```
#<Location:0x0000000006eee1d8
 id: 35456173,
 name: "Paris",
 nickname: "paris",
 retailer_id: 399879241,
 created_at: Wed, 23 May 2018 22:39:56 UTC +00:00,
 updated_at: Wed, 23 May 2018 22:39:56 UTC +00:00>
```

Those id numbers are consistent through multiple calls, at least in the same RSpec context. (I put `pp locations(:loc_paris)` in a `let` block.) Yet `pp locations(:loc_paris).retailer` returns `nil`.

I tried using FactoryBot however we had to switch away from it. I am trying to give fixtures an honest shake but it seems like we are best off simply building data objects in the actual test code... because that solutions works without complaining :/

Am I doing something wrong here? Are we asking too much of fixtures?

Thank you!

Tom

Comment: This should help https://stackoverflow.com/a/26637179/4758119

Comment: Are the ID’s “random” or sequentially higher across runs of rspec?  Can you include one complete rspec file where you are running this test?  In the same block where you test location.retailer, can you also run ‘pp retailers(:ret_europe)’  also, run .valid? Against both objects to see if you are having some sort of validation error.  All-in-all, this should generally work, so not sure why it wouldn’t.  Oh, can you confirm you are enforcing referential integrity on the tables as well?

Comment: While the answer solves the problem I do want to note that some of the other classes in the project (not these ones) have some code that runs in the before_validation handler, which expects certain associations to be present. In the normal application workflow this is not a problem but I have noticed that building those same objects using fixtures can be problematic as those expected associations aren't present. I will look into that further but it is a bit puzzling as the included samples don't have any such logic and still have the issue.

Comment: Also, I am not aware of postgres-enforced CREATE PRIMARY KEY or somesuch, AR is supposed to be handling that on the Ruby side. Or did that change with newer versions of Rails? This project was originally upgraded from 4.1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Problem with fixtures**

Looking at what you've done, `locations(:loc_paris)` will find the record described in *locations.yml*, but `locations(:loc_paris).retailer` won't.

**Rails Associations work like this:**

`locations(:loc_paris).retailer` will look for the `retailer` with `retailer_id` mentioned in `locations(:loc_paris)` record. In your case `retailer_id: 399879241` and there is no `reseller` with this `id` that's why it returns `Nil`.

**Solution:**
Describe fixtures like this:

```
#spec/fixtures/locations.yml
loc_paris:
  retailer_id: 1
  name: "Paris"
  nickname: "paris"

loc_washington:
  retailer_id: 2
  name: "Washington"
  nickname: "washington"

#spec/fixtures/retailers.yml
ret_europe:
  id: 1
  name: "AcmeCo France"
  nickname: "acmecofr"
  currency_type: "EUR"

ret_usa:
  id: 2
  name: "AcmeCo USA"
  nickname: "acmecousa"
  currency_type: "USD"
```

Now, `locations(:loc_paris).retailer` will look for the retailer with `retailer_id` mentioned in `locations(:loc_paris)` record i.e. `retailer_id: 1` and there is a reseller `ret_europe` with this `id`. **Problem Solved**

**When you run rspec, at first `rspec` saves these fixtures into your database with some auto-generated `id` values (if `id` not provided explicitly), that's why `id` and `reseller_id` are some random values**. If you don't want the `id` of `locations.yml` record to be some random value, you can provide it yourself like this:

```
loc_paris:
  id: 1
  retailer_id: 1
  name: "Paris"
  nickname: "paris"
```

**Tips:**
As `rspec` runs in `test` environment (mentioned in *app/spec/rails_helper.rb*) and as I mentioned earlier whenever you run `rspec`, at first it saves the fixtures into your database. If your `local` and `test` database are same, fixtures will replace the actual database records of your database. In your case, records in `locations` and `resellers` table record will be completely erased and replaced with these fixtures. So, make different database for `test` environment.

**Hope this answer is helpful**

Comment: So I have considered this but the docs seem to imply that specifying your own ID wasn't necessary. I would certainly prefer if I could trust the ORM or fixtures to handle it. I know that fixtures knows about the object because if I call out a fixture that doesn't exist it throws an error. Nonetheless, this does solve the problem and I've marked this as an answer. Thank you!

Comment: I don't know what your  _location_spec.rb_ looks like. But, for your code to work without implementing my previously mentioned solution you should include both fixtures in _location_spec.rb_. _location_spec.rb_ should contain these lines `fixtures :locations` `fixtures :retailers` inside RSpec context where you're using `pp locations(:loc_paris).retailer`

Comment: And @TomCorelis please remove `(Retailer)` from these lines `retailer: ret_europe (Retailer)` and `retailer: ret_usa (Retailer)`