# Rails fixture associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, minitest, fixtures

Struggling to get fixtures to associate. We are (finally!) writing tests for an existing app. We are using Minitest as the framework.

`mail_queue_item.rb`:

```
class MailQueueItem < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :order
  ...
end
```

`mail_queue_items.yml`:

```
one:
  run_at: 2015-01-04 10:22:19
  mail_to: test@test.com
  order: seven_days_ago
  email_template: with_content
  customer: basic_customer
  status: waiting
```

`orders.yml`:

```
seven_days_ago:
  tenant: basic_tenant
  ecom_store: basic_store
  ecom_order_id: 123-123456-123456
  purchase_date: <%= 7.days.ago %>
  set_to_shipped_at: <%= 6.days.ago %>
  ecom_order_status: shipped
  fulfillment_channel: XYZ
  customer: basic_customer
```

In a test:

```
require 'test_helper'
class MailQueueItemDenormalizerTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase
  fixtures :mail_queue_items, :customers, :email_templates, :orders

  test 'should make hash' do
    @mqi = mail_queue_items(:one)

    puts @mqi.order_id.inspect
    puts @mqi.order.inspect

    order = orders(:seven_days_ago)
    puts order.inspect

    assert @mqi.order.ecom_order_status == 'shipped'
  end
end
```

The output looks like this:

```
MailQueueItemDenormalizerTest
447558226
nil
#<Order id: 447558226, tenant_id: 926560165, customer_id: 604023446, ecom_order_id: "123-123456-123456", purchase_date: "2022-08-13 19:18:02.000000000 -0700", last_update_date: nil, ecom_order_status: "shipped", fulfillment_channel: "XYZ", ....>
  test_should_make_hash                                          ERROR (5.96s)
Minitest::UnexpectedError:         NoMethodError: undefined method `ecom_order_status' for nil:NilClass
            test/denormalizers/mail_queue_item_denormalizer_test.rb:26:in `block in <class:MailQueueItemDenormalizerTest>'
```

So even though the `order_id` on the `mail_queue_item` is correct (it matches the `id` from the object loaded from the fixture) the association does not work.

I have tried the suggestions in [Nil Associations with Rails Fixtures... how to fix?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50498543/nil-associations-with-rails-fixtures-how-to-fix) of putting ids in everything and the result is the same.

Project is in Rails 6 (long project that started life in Rails 3.1).

Comment: Are you sure that the association isn't working? From the code shared, it's possible that `inspect` isn't doing what we expect, but the fixtures are associated. What's the actual behavior of the test?

Comment: Thanks @JakeWorth - the test fails with a nil pointer when trying to use `mqi.order`

Comment: I noticed your `mail_queue_item.yml` filename is singular; the docs use plural names (`mail_queue_items.yml`). Does changing that change the test's behavior?

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo. Fixing now. It is plural.

Comment: "the test fails with a nil pointer when trying to use mqi.order" -> could you share the  test assertion that's failing, and the failure output?

Comment: @JakeWorth I'm updating the question now with an `assert` and the failure output.

Comment: My suspicion is that something is off with the ActiveRecord association. When you assign an order to a mail queue item in the Rails console, any issue?

Comment: No...This is an existing app that has been running for more than 5 years. Just adding additional testing.

Comment: I'm out of ideas. If you could link to a small Rails app repository that reproduces the issue, might be able to make progress.

Comment: Aha! It seems that the fixture definitions created invalid objects. So it was saving them but they could not be used. I am now onto another problem with this!

Answer (score 0):

The issue turned out to be that the fixtures were creating invalid objects. The objects were valid enough to get written to the database, but were not passing the Rails validations.

The resulting behavior is quite odd I think, but I don't know of a better way to do it.

I discovered this by adding:

```
    puts "@mqi.order.valid? = #{@mqi.order.valid?}"
    puts "@mqi.customer.valid? = #{@mqi.customer.valid?}"
    puts "@mqi.email_template.valid? = #{@mqi.email_template.valid?}"
    puts @mqi.email_template.errors.full_messages
```

code in there. Yes, it's disgusting.

Comment: I can't find an official doc that explains it, but my understanding is that fixture data does not get run through the validations.